# Adding an alt attribute in an Array

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to figure how to add a Alt Attribute to a array. Here is what I have so far. How would I add that in and where? I was thinking in the body/table adding alt=' "  but obvious this don't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var pictures = new Array();
        pictures[0] = new Image();
        pictures[0].src = "image.jpg";
        pictures[1] = new Image();
        pictures[1].src = "image2.jpg";



<body>
    var x = "<table>";
        for (var y=0; y<rows; y++) {
            x += "<tr> ";
            for (var j=0; j<columns; j++) {
                var ix = (y * rows + j) % pictures.length;
                var id = y + "-" + j;

                x += "<td> <img src=' " + pictures[ix].src + 
                     "' " +
                     " id='" + id + "' " +
                     " height='300' width='300' ></td>";
```

Comment: Hey @ohdust, did the answer not work out for you? what is the problem so we can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

"Alt" is in case the image does not display correctly, so the text inside the attribute will show.

```
                     x += "<td> <img src=' " + pictures[ix].src + 
                     "' " +
                     " id='" + id + "' " +
                     " height='300' width='300' alt='image_" + j + "'  ></td>";
```